# Only Allowing IPv4 and HTTPS in Firewall

Tags: security, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, ufw

I've got a Ubuntu Machine in the cloud, running a Web Server with Nginx and Node.js.
In the firewall settings (`ufw`), I've only allowed ipv4 through port 443 (ssl)  for inbound connections (And ssh of course).

Is preventing regular HTTP and/or ipv6 connection a problem? And why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is preventing regular HTTP and/or ipv6 connection a problem?

If all URL's pointing to your server are only `https://` and all IP addresses setup in DNS for your system are only IPv4 and you don't need to have any other services on this machine accessible from outside (i.e. SSH, mail, ...) then you expect only IPv4 TCP traffic on port 443 and your restriction makes sense. But, if any of these limitations regarding URL, DNS and services are not true then you probably deny valid traffic which will be a problem.

Comment: Seems Logical :)